# Alterar o valor do ToolStripStatus enquanto digito no RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um editorzinho de texto só pra praticar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas me deparei com um probleminha, 
eu queria que enquanto o usuário estiver digitando, o valor do ToolStripStatus que por padrão está 'PRONTO', queria alterar enquanto digita de 'PRONTO' PARA 'DIGITANDO...'

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: acredito que seja um processamento muito desnecessário, mas se quer assim vou postar um codigo que pode ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai precisar de:

1-RichTextBox: `richTextBox1`

1-ToolStripStatusLabel: `toolStripStatusLabel1`

1-Timer: `timer1`, com intervalo de 300ms

Utilize o evento TextChanged do `richTextBox1`:

```
 private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Digitando...";
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Utilize o evento Tick do `timer1`:

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Pronto!";
  }
```

Comment: PERFEITO.........